# C++ program exiting early when calling a function

Tags: c++

Why is my program exiting early? It is unfinished, and will have two more functions, one to average the number, one to display the average.

When I run the program through visual studio it exits the program after the first "Score1: " is displayed. Why isn't it going into the getScore() function?

It works when I place the program in an online compiler, just not when I compile and run from visual studio.

```
 // Lab 8-1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
 //


 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

void printInfo();       // printInfo prototype
int getScore();         // getScore prototype

int main()
{
    int score1 = 0, score2 = 0, score3 = 0;     // declare variables

     printInfo();       // call printInfo function

    cout << endl << "Score 1: ";        // output: ask for first score
    score1 = getScore();                // assign value to integer through getScore function
    cout << endl << "Score 2: ";
    score2 = getScore();
    cout << endl << "Score 3: ";
    score3 = getScore();

    return 0;
}

// ******************************************************
// * The printInfo function displays a message about    *
// * what the program does                              *
// ******************************************************
void printInfo()
{
    cout << "This program accepts 3 integer scores between\n";
    cout << "0 and 50 (inclusive), and displays the average\n";
    cout << "of the three tests.\n\n";
}

// **********************************************************
// * The getScore function takes in a value from the user,  *
// * validates the input, and returns an int value          *
// **********************************************************
int getScore()
{
    int score;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (score < 0 || score > 50)
    {
        cout << "\nScore must be >= 0 or <= 50." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a new score:";
        cin >> score;
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: Yes, the output is as follows: The thread 0x3c08 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3dec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4148 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11304] Lab 8-1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: I mean actually debugging before your program dies.  And stepping through the code.

Comment: your code is ok which gets 3 score inputs. try to close your compiler and create a new project pasting your code, recompile and run

Comment: Yes, but it goes out of my program into a bunch of code that is way over my head.

Comment: your compiler may crash while executing the program; as I said you can execute your program from a command prompt for example and see the result. if it is ok then the problem is from your vs

Comment: @raindrop7, I just tried recompiling and running, same issue

Comment: Try commenting out the body of `getScore()` and add `return 42;`. Rebuild and run. What happens then?

Comment: have you tried it from command prompt or a terminal?

Comment: In debug mode the program opens and closes without waiting for you (Visual Studio). Press Ctrl-F5 to run without debugging. Or add `system("pause");` at the end.

Comment: You don't check for failure to read user input, and you don't eat up newlines. We go over this here on Stack Overflow every single day.

Comment: @Arun, when I just have return 42; in the body of the getScore function, I have the same output.

Comment: @stares_at_flames: What do you mean by "same"?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I usually "start without debugging" , and thus the program opens in command prompt.

Comment: @Arun, it still exits after the output of "Score 1: ", and the debugger shows the same as my response above. Three threads exit with code 0, and then program exits with 0.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, can you elaborate? I'm assuming the similar issues are for other programming students who still don't have those things included in their programs. This is just bare bones.

Comment: I compile your code on vs 2015 and it works as it should!!

Comment: or just try to flush the buffer after any input: `cin.ignore(1, '\n');`

Comment: @Raindrop7 Thank you! At least that let's me know it's not in my code. I will try the flush to see if that helps.

Comment: @stares_at_flames: welcome! flush input buffer after any input in your getscore() and add `cin.get();` or `system("pause");` at the end of main. I wish it will help you.

Comment: The final solution was actually to restart my computer. Copying the code into a new project and restarting VS were not sufficient, but a full reboot did the trick! Thank you to all who added input.